# Making a private cocoapod with dependencies on other cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, dependency-management

I've read all the tutorials (some less deeply than others), and discovered that there is a huge focus on using the `pod lib create` command and how to get your new cocoapod into the the podspec repo and available to other developers, but they are all missing the middle part involving actually setting up and developing your pod, Xcode example project, etc..

I'm trying to make a cocoapod for internal use that has dependencies on other pods.  I told `pod lib create` that I wanted an example project and now I need to be able to build and run it using the pods it depends on. I'm not clear on how I actually get those pods to download.  I understand that there is a podspec syntax for specifying dependencies:
 `spec.dependency 'SOMEPOD', '~> VER.0'`, but that doesn't do much for my example project.

Am I supposed to make a Podfile in the folder with my example project? Does that conflict with the podspec somehow?  Do I need to include the pod I'm making in that podfile? Should I not be using an example project and just be developing my pod in conjunction with a test project that pulls my pod in like any other cocoapod?

Also, when all my testing is said and done, does the example project get distributed with the pod and set up as a weird sub-target in whatever project uses the pod? Or do I eventually have to make a different repo that just has the pod (without the example project)?

Comment: Apparently I can't read.  I found the podfile included with the example project, but I'm still curious about the proper way to distribute the whole cocoapod (with or without the demo project).

Comment: Have you found the answers for your questions?